# sealing off sunroom to a/c in summer

Tags: hvac, cooling, saving-money

what's the best way to seal off our sunroom so we don't pay to cool it?  It's really humid AND hot in MS this time of year (avg 90+ F).  We have a very "open" house, with a large dining room connected to the sunroom by one normal "door hole" AND one "double door hole", but the openings are...well, openings.  There's nothing at all there.  The sunroom doesn't have a/c, and only has single pane windows...about 10-15 of them, floor to ceiling.  It's a round room with practically no wall except between the windows.

Solutions?
-door(s)?
-curtain(s)?
-"magnet" curtain(s)?
-blanket(s)?

We rent the house, so major reconstruction isn't a reality.  Nor a desire...

Thanks!

edit: infrequent access is still necessary to the room.

Comment: Are you trying to block all the light as well? Does the sunroom have any external doors?

Comment: the room itself isn't as important.  Ideally I should also tint all of the windows.  There is indeed one standard, large single pane door that goes to the back deck/yard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheap, effective, non-intrusive...  Adjustable shower rod with heavy curtains - this will help a ton.  If you never want to use the room... stand up an old matress or something similar.

Comment: hanging some type of movable barrier seems to be the only plan.  Was just looking for some creative/innovative ideas that we may have been missing.  Thanks!

Comment: any tips of "type" of curtains?

Comment: Thick blackout curtains would work the best.  The key is to make sure it covers ceiling to floor.  The more gaps the more hot air that escapes.

Comment: Also if you block it take the temperature inside the room.  If it is hotter than your nightly temperatures I would open the windows for that room at night.

Comment: I should also comment that you should have something over (blinds, curtains) the windows in the sunroom too.